# Server side login, clients send requests without logging in and get the output

Tags: php, server-side

So, I am a total newb in this and I am not sure if what I am asking is implementable, therefore I would like to at least get some directions if not the actual answers. 
What I am trying to do:

- I have a php server with wordpress.
- I want to run a php file on the server independantly from clients. This file.php will have a function which initializes an account and performs a log in, like this:

  require_once 'Client.php';

  $client = new Client('username', 'password');

Logging in takes from 7 to 18 seconds to complete, so I want to execute the login once and never logout.

- now if the client wants to use some specific account related functions like this : $client->function(), the client doesn't have to login. Instead, it sends a request to the server, the server executes the function call, since $client is already initialized on the server, and sends back the output to the client.
- the client reads the output and interprets it in whatever way it wants.

I want to do things this way, because as I have mentioned logging in takes about 10 seconds, while executing functions when the $client is initialized takes about 1-2 seconds and as a result the users get fast responses and do not have to wait ~10 seconds each time they call a function.
In other words, users all execute functions through one global (server side) account, not local client-side accounts.

If what I am asking is possible, how do I do it?

Comment: This sounds very confusing. I don't understand the part about logging in. Typically you don't have to log in on each request, that's what the session cookie is for. Can you clarify?

Comment: What’s in your `Client` class? Why can’t you use WordPress’s native user system?

Comment: I don't want the users to ever log in. They just go to the website and send some requests to the server. There is a permanent account on the server (always logged in) and all the users use this account. The server-side account doesn't care if the users leave the website, it's just always on and processes all the requests from the users. I know it sounds confusing, even to me, so I am not sure if this is possible, but I have a feeling that there must be a way....

Comment: Why is logging in required? Isn't there a way to bypass this log-in process?

Comment: I didn't want to go into details, but ok, I'll explain. I have an account on another server, and the users do not have such accounts. On my php server I am establishing an RTMP stream connection to that server and log in (this is why it takes ~10 seconds). The users do not have such accounts but I want to give them access to that server via my account in a queue. That's why logging in is required.
I am thinking of some sort of event listener on the server side